# TextView in Listview onclick conflict

Tags: java, android, listview

I have made an Listview populated with list_row_layout.xml(which is populated with json serializable class), i have clickable textview and onclick changing text from "Accept" to "Accepted". But when i click it on first listview item, another textview listview items below are changing. Here's some photos to descibe you bettet.

[image: before]
after clicking the accept in first row
 [image: after clicking the accept in first row]
 in Activity class

```
      feedListView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, feedList));
```

ListAdapter class

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
   {
 private ArrayList<FeedItem> listData;
 private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
 private Context mContext;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> listData)
{
this.listData = listData;
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
mContext = context;
 }

@Override
public int getCount()
{
return listData.size();
}

 @Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
 return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
final ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null)
{
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.headlineView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.confid);
    holder.approve = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.approveTV);

    holder.approve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View argView)
            {
                holder.approve.setText("accepted");
            }
        }
    );

    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

FeedItem newsItem = listData.get(position);

holder.headlineView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getTitle()));
holder.reportedDateView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getContent()));

holder.approve.setTag(newsItem);



return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
TextView approve;
TextView headlineView;
TextView reportedDateView;
ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual solution is not implemented correctly. I think that problem is that your rows are not corectly recycled - exactly problem is i think this:

```
holder.approve.setText("accepted");
```

Try to change it to:

```
((TextView) argView).setText("accepted");
```

and this should work. 
But i suggest you to change your application logic. Look at your current solution. You're assigning for each row *OnClickListener*. In the case you'll have for example **1000+ rows** it won't be *efficient*, isn't? And for this reason and also for better performance i recommend you to create only one *OnClickListener* (let adapter class implements **View.OnClickListener**) and then just assign for each row that listener:

```
holder.approve.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And in **onClick()** method do same as above:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   ((TextView) v).setText("accepted");
}
```

<strike>Now everything should work properly</strike>. *@Geralt solution updated bellow*

## Update:

Problem is slightly bigger because

- Collection know nothing about that you have changed row's text. When **getView()**
  method is called you are filling Adapter with data from collection
  but how i mentioned collection don't know about runtime changes "you" did **if
  you won't update collection**

I tried to preserve your origin solution with *OnClickListener* but now i think it's not correct solution. So let's make working solution:

### Solution:

At first you need to use [`OnItemClickListener`](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) instead of current listener - it's directly designated for AdapterView subclasses. Contains handy information lke whole row with its content, position in Adapter simply information you need.

Then you need to create mechanism that your collection items *"won't forget that were clicked"*. This can be done:

- Next property in Item that represents row for example **boolean variable
  isClicked** (when you'll click on row, just find item in collection at clicked position and change it's property to true)<sup>**1**</sup>
- Create list of positions which were clicked (when you click on row,
  save its position into that List)<sup>**2**</sup>

Then you should be able to achieve correct behaviour. Now all what you need is to correctly use these information in **getView()** method that creates rows. Do something like this:

**#Solution with property (pseudo-code):**

```
...
final Item i = collection.get(position);
if (i.isClicked()) {
   // set text accepted
}
else {
   // set text normal
}
```

**#Solution with list of positions (pseudo-code):**

```
...
final Item i = collection.get(position);
if (positions.indexOf(position) > 0) {
   // set text accepted
}
else {
   // set text normal
}
```

At the end is example of **onItemClick()** method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View row, int position, long id) { 
   // solution with list of positions:
   myAdapterClass.addPosition(position);

  // solution with property
  myAdapteClass.setItemClicked(position);

  // update immediate after click row
  ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId)).setText("Accepted");
}
```

And methods in Adapter class:

```
public void addPosition(position) {
   // if position is not in list
   if (positions.indexOf(position) < 0) {
      positions.add(position);
   }
}

public void setItemClicked(position) {
   // finds clicked item
   if (collection.get(position) != null) {
      collection.get(position).setIsClicked(true);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps you man / girl and solve your problem.

Comment: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (CustomListAdapter)

Comment: @SandraMladenovic Did you read my answer carefully? Implements your adapter class View.OnClickListener?

Comment: I did implement it and copied your code, but didn't helped me, other textviews being clicked too, like on my picture in this question

Comment: in list_row_layout i have 4 linear layouts and one relative as parent, could this be the problem? and the way i invite adapter object in activity class  feedListView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, feedList));  ?